# How to conditionally render fields with a different formatter

Tags: entities, theming

I have a content type with two fields one called display which is a simple list and the other is an entityreference field.

I would like to change how the entity reference field is rendered depending on which option is selected in the first field.

I have custom formatters installed and I have created two custom formatters so I need a way of changing the #formatter based on the result in the first field.

I've tried a hook_preprocess_node() and also changing it in a custom tpl file but neither seem to render the field any differently to how it is set in the manage field UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did this in the tpl file for my content type using field_view_field(), I hide both fields the one that contains the option and the second that contains the data. I then use a case statement to set the correct formatter.

```
  hide($content['field_display_mode']);
  hide($content['field_link']);
  print render($content);
  $links_display_mode = $content['field_display_mode']['#items']['0']['value'];
  switch($links_display_mode) {
    case 1:
      $links_formatter = 'custom_formatters_entry_form_display_one';
      break;
    case 2:
      $links_formatter = 'custom_formatters_entry_form_display_two';
  }      
  $field_link = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_link', array('label' => 'hidden', 'type' => $links_formatter));
  print render($field_link);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the [Context module API](http://drupalcode.org/project/context.git/blob/refs/heads/6.x-3.x:/API.txt) and adding a new reaction plugin.

Comment: Yeah I think the overhead of context is a little overkill